# Unable to pass the parameter while creating the scheduled task using powershell. I should get -version as "sql server 2016" instead of "sql"

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to create a scheduled task using powershell.

able to create and execute the task properly

````
```
$servername ="myservername"
# Issue with the version, unable to pass. Splitting in the scheduler argument.
$version="sql server 2016" 
$edition="enterprise"

$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute Powershell.exe -Argument "-File G:\ForAPI\MainFunctions_All.ps1 -Servername $servername -Version $version -Edition $edition"

$trigger =  New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At 12:00PM
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "MSSQL" -Description "SQL Deployment"
```
````

I should get -version as "sql server 2016" instead of "sql"

Comment: you're not wrapping the strings with double quotes

Comment: Forgot to mention, I have already tried with "double quotes" also... "No use"

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the parameters as positional and make it in order like 1st `servername` ,then `version` followed by `edition` in the function where you are using it.

You should use single quotes for the parameters inside while the value is being held by them else you will observe partial record(exactly what you are getting now); Change the quotation like this below:

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Argument "-ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File G:\ForAPI\MainFunctions_All.ps1 '$servername' '$version' '$edition'"
```

If the parameters are all positional then you can completely avoid the `-Servername` , `-Version` and `-Edition` unnecessarily.

This will do the trick for you. Hope it helps.

Comment: If I pass it with the single quotes it is passing param value as $version only, I should get the value as "sql server 2016" in task scheduler argument.

Comment: Ya. So you need to order the parameters one by one. I have tested with three values hardcoding the parametes in the string and it is reflecting properly inside the argument list

Comment: In normal scenario it is working fine... Issue is while registering a scheduled job in task scheduler there it is failing to pass the parameters. try from your end with the same parameters to register as task. It will not work.